# Cocos2d-x: Create simple progress bar

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm newbie in Cocos2d-x.

I want to create simple progress/update bar for my game.

When this progress bar is full, we will move to next level.

How can i create that bar.

Thanks for all your helps.

Answer (score 2):

See this - [How to use a progress bar in cocos2d-x and C++](http://www.aeonphyxius.com/2013/06/how-to-use-a-progress-bar-in-cocos2d-x-and-c/)

Basically, create two sprites one for the progress bar's border and one for the loading bar itself.

```
CCPointer  fuelBarBorder;

fuelBarBorder = 
     CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName ("bt_progressbarborder.png" );
fuelBarBorder->setPosition(ccp(100,100));
this->addChild(fuelBarBorder,1);




// CCProgresstimer object (smart pointer) 
CCPointer  fuelBar; 
fuelBar = CCProgressTimer::create(
     CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName ("bt_progressbar.png" ));
```

Set the loading bar sprite's type to `CCProgressTimerType`.

```
// Set this progress bar object as kCCProgressTimerTypeBar (%)
fuelBar->setType(CCProgressTimerType::kCCProgressTimerTypeBar);

// Set anchor point in 0,0 and add it as a child to our border sprite
fuelBar->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0,0));

fuelBar->setBarChangeRate(ccp(1,0)); // To make width 100% always
fuelBar->setTag(1);                  // Tag our object for easy access

fuelBarBorder->addChild(fuelBar,50); // Add it inside the border sprite
```

In your update method, change its `percentage` to reflect loading percentage.

```
fuelBar->setPercentage(80); // Value between 0-100
```

Comment: I try but CCPointer do not exist, I don't know why.

Comment: I have got the lastest vesion of Cocos2d-x

Comment: @Tom just use `CCSprite` in place of `CCPointer` , it should work

Comment: Thanks, i will try in my project

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the original post (link above).

Thanks to this post, I found out that WordPress played me ... when saving the code:(.

There is some corrections to be made:

```
CCPointer <CCSprite> fuelBarBorder; 

fuelBarBorder = 
  CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName ("bt_progressbarborder.png" ); 

fuelBarBorder->setPosition(ccp(100,100)); 

this->addChild(fuelBarBorder,1);
```

This for the first set, as you can see the only change is at the first line:

```
CCPointer <CCSprite> fuelBarBorder;
```

If you don't have this cocos2d-x extension, just use the following:

```
CCSprite * fuelBarBorder;
```

Same on the second set of code, the correct one is:

```
CCPointer <CCProgressTimer> fuelBar;

fuelBar = CCProgressTimer::create(
 CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName ("bt_progressbar.png" ));
// Set this progress bar object as kCCProgressTimerTypeBar (%)
fuelBar->setType(CCProgressTimerType::kCCProgressTimerTypeBar);

// Set anchor point in 0,0 and add it as a child to our border sprite
fuelBar->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0,0));

fuelBar->setBarChangeRate(ccp(1,0)); // To make width 100% always
fuelBar->setTag(1);                  // Tag our object for easy access

fuelBarBorder->addChild(fuelBar,50); // Add it inside the border sprite
```

Same thing is using an CCPointer (smart pointer implementation), if you don't have it in your project, just change the following line:

```
CCPointer <CCProgressTimer> fuelBar;
```

by this one:

```
CCProgressTimer fuelBar;
```

An this should make the code works, I hope this helps !!!!